# How do I get a list of all delegators of an address using TzScan API v3?

Tags: delegating, tzscan, api

In TzScan.io API v3, I currently use https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rewards_split/ endpoint to get a list of known delegators of an address. Occurs that using this method, the information is linked to a cycle. So, it returns a list of the delegators from a specific cycle.

I would like to get a list of all delegators a baker have, including recently added new ones, even if they are not receiving any rewards (just like appears in a baker's page on TzScan delegators tab). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to our friend Klassare, who helped me in Riot channel, we've got an answer:

https://api3.tzscan.io/v3/delegated_contracts/[account]?p=0&number=50

Comment: Please don’t forget to mark your question as “resolved” !